# noise in my rear end when slowing down

Tags: ford, noise, f-350, rear-end

Hi I have a 1988 f350 ford with a big block. I just got new tires on her a couple of days back and I am hearing a clicking sound in my rear end when I slow down. when I make a turn it gets louder then goes a way. What should i do???

It seems like its the axle but I don't know I thought it was my drive shaft but its not I don't know if it could be a gearing my rear axle that is shot??

Answer (score 0):

If the noise is close to the wheel it will most likley be your wheel bearing and will need to be changed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it is, this answer is really lacking. You could make it stand out by giving the OP a description of why you understand this could be their issue. You could also go through ways to help them diagnose it beyond you just telling them it is probably one thing or another. There's a lot of information out there ... bring it to the site! Looking forward to what you have to say :o)

Answer (score 0):

Put vehicle on jack stands and slowly spin rear wheels in low gear then let off you should be able to pin point where the sound emanates from.The pinion gear which is the gear in the center of your rear axle may be backlashing ( has too much or too little play).Remove drive shaft and tighten or loosen large nut to adjust play. You will have to replace seal &  Check fluid in the rear axle fill to bottom of fill hole. Barring in the center and at both axle ends could be worn and you could hear them.